# Monitoring my account with Twitter4J in real time

Tags: java, twitter, real-time, twitter4j

Hello I want to monitor ONLY my account with twitter4j in real time

I want to get the notifications i get on twitter, and only my notifications

In addition, if it's possible i want to get the tweets i get on the main page of twitter when i'm on the website. Is it possible with twitter4j ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution you have to use

https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/stream/PrintUserStream.java

UserStream from twitter4j